# boolean assignment in freemarker using conditional statements

Tags: boolean, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, freemarker

In freemarker, can you assign a boolean value like this:

```
[#if something = value]
    [#assign bool = true]
[/#if]
```

To then be used in a conditional statement like this:

```
[#if bool]
    ...do something
[/#if]
```

So far I have not been successful doing this in this format, but thought I might be missing something. Do i need to declare the variable outside the first if statement to keep it in scope and reuse later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the error message... but I guess your problem is that if the first condition is false, then you never assign to the `bool` variable, so it won't exist at all, and so you can't use it in the second expression. To fix that, the first `#if` could to be changed to:

```
[#assign bool = something == value]
```